# Redirect with $_POST variable

Tags: php, variables, post

How can I redirect to a page and add the $_POST variable with some info in it?

I know that with $_GET you have to append the variable to the URL like &var=foo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

Then your POST params will be available via $_SESSION.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the data from `$_POST`, and append it to the redirection URL :

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/test.php?var=' . urlencode($_POST['var']));
```

If you have more parameters, see [`http_build_query()`](http://fr.php.net/http_build_query), to help building the query-string.

But note that this `test.php` page will be loaded by the browser using the `GET` method : the server cannot say to a browser to load another page using `POST`.

Comment: This will however not work for file fields, and URLs should never become larger than 2-4 k due to browser and server restrictions. Storing stuff in a session might be the better option if you deal with large amounts or file data

Comment: True ; just keep in mind that the session in shared between all tabs opened to the same website -- so make sure take that into account.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using a form and some JavaScript.

Here's an example:

```
<form action="/path/to/redirect/to" id="example-id">
    <?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $value): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" />
    <?php endforeach ?>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#example-id").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Note that the example uses [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) for the JavaScript part.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Your options are to

a) append the posted variable to the redirect url and then look at $_GET

b) use a session variable to carry the data from page to page.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do that is using an "Apache RewriteRule" which will send the POST data to the rewritten script.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same kind of problem using a `POST` form and auto-validating with JavaScript.

```
<?php
.. blah blah blah my stuff

$body = "<html><body onload='connexion.submit()'>";
$body .= "<form name='connexion' action='$connectURL' method='post'>";
$body .= "<input type='hidden' name='username' value='$dataLogin'>";
$body .= "<input type='hidden' name='password' value='$dataPassword'>";
$body .= "<input type='submit' value='OK' />";
$body .= "</form>";
$body .= "</body></html>";
?>
```

It fails if JavaScript is disabled on client's browser (user has to submit the form manually), but it's acceptable for my case.