# PHP forward data post

Tags: php

I am trying to forward data from one page to another without using cURL, is this possible?

At the moment i have tried

```
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header('Location: new-location.php');
```

This works nicely but gives a stupid pop up box, any other methods?

I have tried using curl but nothing happens, not sure if its enabled on my server!

Comment: Forward data? The header calls you posted simply do a redirect, and do not use cURL. Am I missing something?

Comment: @stefgosselin: The word "without", apparently.

Comment: Yes i know they do a simple redirect, but it carries the data with it. only problem is it gives a stupid popup box alerting the user

Comment: @Lunar: By what metric is it "stupid"?

Comment: Do you do this after a form submit or something?

Comment: where do u get a popup? what does it say?

Comment: @Lunar: When you say "post", you mean HTTP POST, right?

Comment: yeah HTTP POST, basically my form submits to itsself (with form data), generates a file, then redirects to anouther PHP page, however i wish to carry the POST data to that new page!

Comment: This is what is happening: http://jfcoder.com/test/easyform.php It's a warning that the POST data is being sent to a new page, similar to the "Do you want to resubmit POST form data?"-type alert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect with $_POST variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462978/redirect-with-post-variable)

Comment: @Jared Farrish . correct, this is what is happening, i would like that functionality without the pop up :/

Comment: @Lunar - Look at the link from netcoder. Your choices are realistically storing it in a SESSION variable or appending the POST data to the URL and reading it as a GET string.

Comment: @Lunar: Did you try `303`? See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html (also see 10.3.8 in that document for why `307` will prompt the user about the redirect).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think following is the only possible way to achieve that, instead of redirecting with location header, send this html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form action="new-location.php" method="post">
            <?php foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ): ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?= htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript is not very robust for form submits, better using server-side scripting for this.

Comment: @stefgosselin: so what do you suggest to write in PHP in order to forward the POST data?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio - See my answer below. Although my answer was downvoted, I tend to favor server-side processing for redirects.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the following to forward post data to another url. Notice that the response is captured in the $data variable, with which you can do whatever you want.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.tld/urltopostto.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Could you just put `return $data;` and effectively wrap the POST call?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly and you're working on an Apache server with `mod_rewrite` enabled, you could use URL rewriting. You could set the request method as a condition and rewrite the original URL to the alternate one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
RewriteRule ^index.php new-location.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using cURL or fopen() are common suggestions, but neither actually "forwards" the user to the other page.

To truly forward the user to another page with $_POST data intact, you can create an intermediate page dynamically that contains a form with the post data and JS code that submits the form immediately (along with a button or link to submit the form if the user does not have JS enabled).

You then forward the user to that intermediate page, and it forwards the user to the target page with the #_POST data intact. If the intermediate page has no visible content, the user won't know it's there.

The target page could unlink the intermediate page so there's no chance of a re-submission.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, just maybe you can try it this way:

```
header("Status: 200");
header("Location: new-location.php");
exit;
```

Comment: A header call will not send data, unless you set the variable at the end of your url, a la GET ..

header("Location: new-location.php?var1=$var1&var2=$var2");

Ugly but it would work. You could also use sessions.

Comment: Then you haven't answered the question. :)

Comment: You have 2 choices from what I can gather, javascript as posted above (I don't recommend) or sessions.

Comment: "A header call will not send data, unless you set the variable at the end of your url, a la GET .. header("Location: new-location.php?var1=$var1&var2=$var2"); Ugly but it would work. You could also use sessions. " this worked for me in the end thanks

Comment: @Lunar - If this is what worked for you,  maybe set the answer as the favored answer?.  The selected solution currently relies on javascript and though it works seems lest robust than a 100% server-side redirect.