# save value when going from one html to another

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a value on a textBox on html:

```
<input type="text" id="Key" name="Key" required />
```

then I send action to php and I do this from php:

```
<?php
header("location:./setupDatos.html");//echo "2"; //first time activation
echo '<input type="text" value="' . $varKey. '" />';
```

The problem is, if I remove this line

```
header("location:./setupDatos.html");//echo "2"; //first time activation
```

it shows me a blank page with the key I sent to php (as expected)
but with the line, it changes to new html and the input with the key sent is nowhere. How can I send that value from first html to the next html?

Comment: The HTTP protocol is stateless, therefore to "remember" a previous state you either have to pass it along via `header("Location:./setupDatos.html?oldVariable=$value");` or save it in a session.

Comment: @apokryfos how to get that value from html?

Comment: @apokryfos my conection is via POST not GET by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is stateless, meaning it can't "remember" older post data. However you can use the session to simulate a state.
Try doing something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["oldpostdata"] = $_POST;    
header("location:./setupDatos.html");
```

Not sure what the point is here. An html page wouldn't normally be able to do any server-side processing. If it were able to however you'd access your old post data like:

**setupDatos."html"**

```
<?php    
session_start();
$oldPostData = $_SESSION["oldPostData"];
unset($_SESSION["oldPostData"]); // To only "flash" the data and not have it persist
$id = $oldPostData["Key"]; // Probably
```

Alternative way to "forward" the post data taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180072/php-forward-data-post):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form action="new-location.php" method="post">
            <?php foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ): ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?= htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd rather use hidden values. How to send post value from php to my html and then read it like this:
<input type="hidden" name="name"
value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">  ?

Comment: Added an alternative, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180072/php-forward-data-post . You should really be more clear in what you need in your question though.

Comment: Overall problem is there's no straight-forward way to forward POST parameters the same way you can with GET parameters. It's either do a client-side redirect or use cURL (which is also discussed in the linked question).